# Lodash DifferenceBy not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've been trying to use lodash (4.13.1) _.differenceBy and I must be missing something.

I've got a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cmwye4z1/2/

Here's the javascript:

```
$scope.files_a = [
    {'name': 'file1.wav', 'size': 989010, 'duration': 44.953, 'temp': 1},
    {'name': 'file2.wav', 'size': 326984, 'duration': 14.860, 'temp': 1},
    {'name': 'file3.wav', 'size': 584723, 'duration': 28.583, 'temp': 1},
    {'name': 'file4.wav', 'size': 483829, 'duration': 22.859, 'temp': 1},
    {'name': 'file5.wav', 'size': 283949, 'duration': 9.495, 'temp': 1},
    {'name': 'file6.wav', 'size': 839372, 'duration': 38.584, 'temp': 1},
    {'name': 'file7.wav', 'size': 784949, 'duration': 29.594, 'temp': 1}
];

$scope.files_b = [
    {'name': 'file8.wav', 'size': 989010, 'duration': 44.953, 'temp': 'auto'},
    {'name': 'file2.wav', 'size': 326984, 'duration': 14.860, 'temp': 1}
];

$scope.differenceBy = _.differenceBy($scope.files_a, $scope.files_b, ['name', 'size', 'duration']);
```

And what I expected was:

```
$scope.differenceBy = [
    {'name': 'file1.wav', 'size': 989010, 'duration': 44.953, 'temp': 1},
    {'name': 'file3.wav', 'size': 584723, 'duration': 28.583, 'temp': 1},
    {'name': 'file4.wav', 'size': 483829, 'duration': 22.859, 'temp': 1},
    {'name': 'file5.wav', 'size': 283949, 'duration': 9.495, 'temp': 1},
    {'name': 'file6.wav', 'size': 839372, 'duration': 38.584, 'temp': 1},
    {'name': 'file7.wav', 'size': 784949, 'duration': 29.594, 'temp': 1}
];
```

With file2.wav removed, but what I get is just $scope.files_a.

If I remove the brackets, then I get file3, file4, file5, file6 and file7.

If I understand the documentation correctly, the iteratee can be an array, but maybe I'm mistaken?  Could someone please set me straight?

Comment: My use case is that I'm dealing with large numbers of files and sometimes the filenames may be the same even though the file themselves are different and I want to be able to distinguish between files that may either be identical or may not.

Comment: It's tough to understand what they mean in the docs, and your fiddle is equally mysterious.  My (admittedly lazy) approach would be to make the iteratee a function return the name concat'd with the size in bytes (as a string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment, in other words, is to either wait for an answer from someone smarter about how differenceBy really works with an array argument, or use...

```
$scope.differenceBy = _.differenceBy($scope.files_a, $scope.files_b, function(obj) {
    return obj.name + obj.size;
});
```

which appears to work correctly in your fiddle.

Comment: That does work and I never thought to do something like that.  I'll wait to see if anyone responds with how it's supposed to work since I've been mystified, but thank you danh!

Comment: This... https://leanpub.com/lodashcookbook/read#leanpub-auto-v4-iteratee-shorthand ... seems to indicate that in v4, an two element array `[ key, value ]` is shorthand for `_.matchesProperty( object[key], value)`.  I think, in differenceBy, such an iteratee would map across both arrays, and you'd take the difference based on the resulting booleans.  In your case none of the 'name' properties have the value 'size', so they'd be all false, and therefore all matching.  All this isn't quite borne out, however, in experiments with your fiddle.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right.   I'm starting to think that maybe I can't do what I thought I could.  I was trying to match multiple keys between the two arrays, but that may not be possible looking at the cookbook.

Comment: Yes.  Maybe not possible with the shorthand iteratees.  The point of the shorthand is to be more concise for common simple cases (e.g. a map iteratee the returns a property can be replaced by just the string name of that property).  But we know a complex comparison using multiple properties can be achieved with a longhand function like the one I suggested above.  Also worth noting that there is unlikely any execution advantage to the more concise syntax.  Quicker to type is good, but in this case I doubt that it translates to being quicker to execute.

Comment: Thanks for the help @danh, I've marked your answer.